# how to save activity's data when we want to close the app or back to other activities

Tags: android

For example: we want to enter a string in (edit text)  and this string to be saved when  we want to close the app or return to other activities.

Comment: study about [sharedpreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

Answer (score 2):

For this you will need to use `SharedPreferences`  [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

First you use this to save it:

```
SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();
        prefsEditor.putString(MY_TEXT, edittext.getText().toString());
        prefsEditor.commit();
```

Then when you need to use it again :

```
SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
String prefEdtText = myPrefs.getString(MY_TEXT, 0);
```